# Virtual and Real Images

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses, method-of-images

I am well thorough with the concept of virtual and real images for a single lens/mirror. However I don’t understand how it exactly works for complex system of lens .eg-two or three lens with a silvered surface. If the image formed by the last element (lens/mirror) is real ie. rays actually meet to form an image, can we claim that the entire system produces real image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the terminology for lens systems is the same as for single lenses, at least if you're only interested in the element as a whole. It may produce real/imaginary intermediate images between the elements, but if the rays coming out the end cross to make a real image, you can say the whole element produces a real image.